# How do you rar a windows 10 image backup when permission is denied and changing those permissions fails to enumerate?

Tags: windows-backup

After creating a Windows disk image, I can't rar the folder with the image because access is denied. If I try to apply `"Full permission to all files by clicking Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object"` I get the error `Failed to enumerate objects in the container., Access is denied`. How can I change the permissions to all files in the image backup folder? [error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJRkT.png)

It's possible to change the permissions of the files individually but I don't want to do that every time and I'm not certain that the 13 non .vhdx files are unnecessary to faithfully restore my drive to it's original state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That folders/files are owned by the SYSTEM account. Not by you.
You will have to take ownership first. Then change the permissions.

And this may take several attempts, alternating "taken ownership" and "changing permissions". Start with the top-level folder and then work your way down to the files. Reverse that if neccessary.

It is possible that after the next backup the permission are set back to SYSTEM-only  again. That is the way the Windows internal backup works.

Comment: YES! I would up-vote but I don't have enough points yet. (accepting in 7 minutes).

Comment: You might want to do a test restore to make sure your backup works after these changes.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator That is something you ALWAYS should do after setting up/changing a backup solution. A backup is worthless if it is not restorable. I have seen to many cases of "we got backups so we're OK" until the moment they actually needed that backup...

Comment: @Tonny You and I know the necessity of testing a backup, but that means we probably both also know many people *don't* understand how essential it is.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yeah... I've been in the IT industry for over 30 years now and I still have to pull out the 2 major axioms of backup at least once a week. 1: Restore must be tested. And 2: Raid != backup.

Comment: @Tonny What? I thought RAID-1 was a redundant backup!